# Normal distribution with vector $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, density

Tags: probability, matrices

Let $Z \sim   \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ (normal distribution) with :

$\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\Sigma  = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & -2 & 0\\ 
0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\ 
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I have to say if the vector $Z$ has a density (I suppose yes), and which one. I really don't know how to do it.

Because then, we note $X = \begin{pmatrix}
Z_1\\ 
Z_2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{pmatrix}
Z_3\\ 
Z_4
\end{pmatrix}$ and I have to find the law and the density of $X$ and $X+2Y$. I'm a beginner, and I really need to understand this introductory example. Especially the first point (the density of $Z$). Someone could help me ?

Comment: It has a density unless $\det\Sigma=0.$ Have you seen the expression $$ 
\mathbb{x} \mapsto \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi \det\Sigma}}\, \large e^{(-1/2) (\mathbb{x} - \mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbb{x} - \mu)} \text{ ?} $$

Comment: No, I didn't know this formula :) Thank you !

Comment: How do you find yourself in the position of having to solve this if you know nothing about anything related to normal distributions? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any mad rush to post vast numbers of answers to this, so I'll step in here.

If $\det\Sigma\ne0$ then the density is
$$
\mathbb{x} \mapsto \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi\det\Sigma}} \exp\left( -\frac 1 2 (\mathbb{x}-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1}(\mathbb{x} - \mu) \right).
$$
If $\det\Sigma=0$ then the distribution is supported on some affine subspace of nonzero codimension, i.e. of dimension less than the number of rows or columns of $\Sigma.$ Therefore in that case there is no density with respect to $n$-dimensional volume. To see that that must be true, show that if $\det\Sigma=0$ then there must be some vector $\mathbb {a}$ such that
$$
\operatorname{var}(\mathbb{a}^\top\mathbb{x}) = \mathbb{a}^\top \Sigma\mathbb{a} = 0.
$$